# Woocommerce - Need to charge extra for First Order (Subscription Joining Fee)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress 4.9.7 with latest version of Woocommerce. I am not aware of modifying wordpress/woocommerce code.

My requirement related related to Woocommerce is that whenever a person buy a new product, he needs to pay an extra amount called as a Joining Fee. The joining Fee is different for different products. How can i add this joining fee in the cart as well as the product whenever the customer is buying the product for the first time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function custom_add_cart_fee() {
   $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );
    // Count number of orders
    $count = count( $customer_orders );

    if ( $count == 0 ) 
    {
         WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'Joining Fee', 'your-plugin'), 100 );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_add_cart_fee' );
```